# How to replace the value of a number with reference to its corresponding row name

Tags: excel-formula

I am very new to working with Microsoft Excel and its formula functions. I want to replace the value of 1st `CDS` end value with 2nd `CDS` start value for all `CDS` values. For Example, from the data given below, I want to replace `4663` with `5750`; `7411` with `9003` and so on. What would be the right formula to do the task?

```
RefSeq  region  1   283432
RefSeq  gene    3662    4663
RefSeq  mRNA    3662    4663
RefSeq  exon    3662    4663
RefSeq  CDS 3662    4663
RefSeq  gene    5750    7411
RefSeq  mRNA    5750    7411
RefSeq  exon    5750    7411
RefSeq  CDS 5750    7411
RefSeq  gene    9003    11024
RefSeq  mRNA    9003    11024
RefSeq  exon    9003    11024
RefSeq  CDS 9003    11024
RefSeq  gene    12006   12566
RefSeq  mRNA    12006   12566
RefSeq  exon    12006   12566
RefSeq  CDS 12006   12566
RefSeq  gap 14027   14125
RefSeq  gene    15035   17032
RefSeq  mRNA    15035   17032
RefSeq  exon    15035   17032
RefSeq  CDS 15035   17032
RefSeq  gene    18188   18937
RefSeq  mRNA    18188   18937
RefSeq  exon    18188   18937
RefSeq  CDS 18188   18937
RefSeq  gene    20032   21774
RefSeq  mRNA    20032   21774
RefSeq  exon    20032   21774
RefSeq  CDS 20032   21774
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your data are in Column A, B, C and D as shown below.

[image: example]

You can enter the following **VLOOKUP** function in cell `E2` and drag it down:

```
=IF(B2="CDS",VLOOKUP(B2,B3:D30,2,0),D2)
```

[image: Result]

Then you may use **copy and paste** function to overwrite the figures in Column D with the replaced results in Column E.

The logic is to use **VLOOKUP** to search `CDS` from the full range under the current row and **VLOOKUP** will always return the first match which is exactly what you are after. Then use **IF** function to return the original value from Column D if the look up value is not `CDS`.

Please note the last value is an error `#N/A` as there is no second value for `CDS` after `21774`. If you do not want to show the error message, try apply **IFERROR** function (which you should be able to google the know-how but do let me know if you need any help with it).

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use some combination of `OFFSET()` and `MATCH()`, so the cell `[C9]` will have the formula

```
=OFFSET(D3,MATCH("CDS",B3:B8,0)-1,0)
```

[image]

You will need to supply a "reasonnable" relative range for your `match()` function, so to scan just a "few" cells above the current CDS cell. I chose to look at 6 cells. Be careful not to look at too many rows as you will then find more than one CDS cell! When you copy the function to further CDS cells it will keep using the same relative reference.

`VLOOKUP()` unfortunately requires the search column to be sorted alphabetically, which is not the case here.

The result will look like this

```
RefSeq  region  1   283432
RefSeq  gene    3662    4663
RefSeq  mRNA    3662    4663
RefSeq  exon    3662    4663
RefSeq  CDS 3662    4663
RefSeq  gene    5750    7411
RefSeq  mRNA    5750    7411
RefSeq  exon    5750    7411
RefSeq  CDS 4663    7411
RefSeq  gene    9003    11024
RefSeq  mRNA    9003    11024
RefSeq  exon    9003    11024
RefSeq  CDS 7411    11024
RefSeq  gene    12006   12566
RefSeq  mRNA    12006   12566
RefSeq  exon    12006   12566
RefSeq  CDS 11024   12566
RefSeq  gap 14027   14125
RefSeq  gene    15035   17032
RefSeq  mRNA    15035   17032
RefSeq  exon    15035   17032
RefSeq  CDS 12566   17032
RefSeq  gene    18188   18937
RefSeq  mRNA    18188   18937
RefSeq  exon    18188   18937
RefSeq  CDS 17032   18937
RefSeq  gene    20032   21774
RefSeq  mRNA    20032   21774
RefSeq  exon    20032   21774
RefSeq  CDS 18937   21774
```